# Jquery - InputName no funciona en select

Tags: jquery, ajax

Estoy enviando un formulario desde jquery utilizando ajax, para traer la información lo hago de la siguiente forma:

```
var mrt = $('input[name="mrt"]').val()
var email = $('input[name="email"]').val()
var perfil = $('input[name="perfil"]').val() //Select
var seccion = $('input[name="seccion"]').val() //Select
```

Mi backend esta recibiendo correctamente los valores de los `input text` pero en los `select` me marca `undefined` al parecer no los esta recibiendo corectamente, alguien sabe porque puede estar pasando esto?

Comment: No existe un input select te recomiendo ver  [Select](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)

Comment: no entiendo tu comentario

Comment: @Bryro se refiere a que un combobox no son input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

deberías usarlo así,ya que los valores de los elementos que quieres recoger no son input.además,te interesa recoger los valores que estan seleccionados en ese momento y tienes que inidicar que vas a recoger los options que están seleccionados(texto).

```
$("select[name='perfil'] option:selected").text();
$("select[name='seccion'] option:selected").text();
```

Si lo que quieres es obtener el `value` del `option`seleccionado,tendrás que hacer esto:

```
$("select[name='perfil'] option:selected").val();
$("select[name='seccion'] option:selected").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

En vez de poner

```
var perfil = $('input[name="perfil"]').val();
```

Debes usar:

```
var perfil = $('select[name="perfil"]').val();
```

Ej.

```
<select name="perfil">
    <option value="hola">Hola</option>
    <option value="adios">Adios</option>
</select>
<button id="btn"> Aqui</button>
<script>

    $("#btn").on('click',function(){
        var perfil = $('select[name="perfil"]').val();
        alert(perfil)
    });
</script>
```